# Django rest framework and python3.5 OrderedDict mutated during iteration

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use Django rest framework and python3.5. Earlier I had another version of python and everything was going right. When I want to get some information from server with URL for example like:

> "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/companies"

I'm getting error:

> "OrderedDict mutated during iteration"

.

In views.py I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from companies.models import Companies
from companies.serializers import CompaniesSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework import status


class CompaniesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Companies.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompaniesSerializer


class CompaniesDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Companies.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompaniesSerializer
```

What should I do to make it working? Where is something mutating the dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why using ListCreateApiView is mutating dict, but I changed class into function like :

```
@api_view(['GET'])
    def CompaniesList(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            companies = Companies.objects.all()
            serializer = CompaniesSerializer(companies, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

and now it's working...